# jQuery - chrome lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I've been creating an lightbox myself and everything is ok but only in chrome browser it something bad. I click on thumbnail later i want to change image with next button. Works well, later i click on prev button and i don't know what is happening. On mozilla works great without this problem.

Here's the wideo of my problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38NOYGAT0R0&feature=youtu.be

And here's the code of prev fuction:

```
function prevImage() {

    var img2 = $(".lightbox__img").attr("src");
    src = img2.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
    numberOfImage = parseInt(src, 10);
    if (numberOfImage !== 1) {
        $(".lightbox__img").attr("src", "gallery/(" + (numberOfImage - 1) + ").jpg");
    } else {
        $(".lightbox__img").attr("src", "gallery/(" + 15 + ").jpg");
    }

}
```

Comment: try user-select: none css
https://jsfiddle.net/pn3bry1e/

Comment: Yup it works thank you!

Comment: Could you accept is as an answer?

Comment: Yup i have ban for 8 minutes to accept but after it i will, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try user-select: none. Here is a quick example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pn3bry1e

`<div style='user-select: none'>
   user non-selectable
</div>
<div>
   user selectable
</div>`